Android interstitial ads not showing after updsting form 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0 to 23.0.0
I have recently updated ads services 19.7.0 to 23.0.0 but interstitial ads are not working. Please solve this problem. Providing build.gradle code and my activity code for which I setting up it.
Banner ads is working well with this code. Older virson of ads services working well but pay store not allowed to older virsion for publishing new update. Please solve this. Thanks and regards.
build.gradle (:app)
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
       // classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.9'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
//apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'





android {
    compileSdk 33
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0"
            force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"
            force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:17.0.0"
            force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
            force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

//    packagingOptions {
//        exclude 'META-INF/MethodHandle.invoke'
//        exclude 'META-INF/MethodHandle.invokeExact'
//        exclude 'META-INF/poi-4.1.1.jar'
//    }





    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wbpay.wbpaycal"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.5.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

//        manifestPlaceholders = [
//                onesignal_app_id: '6605d7e1-7ec8-47ea-ad0f-f9baf84a4de9',
//                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
//                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
//        ]
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    //  implementation files('libs/poi-4.1.1.jar')
  //  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'com.github.IntruderShanky:scatter-piechart:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.0.0'

   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.6'


    implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.1"

    //implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.14.1'
    //implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[5.0.0, 5.99.99]'
}


Activity:
package com.wbpay.wbpaycal.activity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
//import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView;


import com.wbpay.wbpaycal.R;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Objects;
//interstitial ad
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;
//ads


public class BonusEligibilityActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG ="BonusCal" ;
    private RadioGroup dojRadioGr;
    private RadioButton beforeAprilRadio;
    private RadioButton betweenAprSepRadio;
    private RadioButton afterSepRadio;
    private EditText basicOfSep;
    private EditText  basicOfMar;
    private Button checkBonusEligibility;
    private ImageView bonusArrowBack;
    private int basicForBonus;
    private int bonusCalDA;
    private int bonusCalEmoluments;

    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private String resultText;
    private int bonusAmount=6000;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private int interstitialCount = -1;



    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bonus_eligibility);

//ads
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        CollapsingToolbarLayout toolBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        toolBarLayout.setTitle(getTitle());

        toolBarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);
        toolBarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppBar);

        dojRadioGr=findViewById(R.id.doj_radio_group);
        beforeAprilRadio=findViewById(R.id.before_april_doj);
        betweenAprSepRadio=findViewById(R.id.between_apr_oct_doj);
        afterSepRadio=findViewById(R.id.after_sep_doj);
        basicOfSep=findViewById(R.id.editText_basic_pay_sep);
        basicOfMar=findViewById(R.id.editText_basicPay_march);
        checkBonusEligibility=findViewById(R.id.button_check_eligibility_bonus);
        bonusArrowBack=findViewById(R.id.bonusArrowBack);



//visibility for edit text field
        dojRadioGr.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId==R.id.before_april_doj){
                    basicOfSep.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    basicOfMar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else if (checkedId==R.id.between_apr_oct_doj){
                    basicOfSep.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    basicOfMar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    basicOfSep.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    basicOfMar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });





//Onclick
        bonusArrowBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        checkBonusEligibility.setOnClickListener(this);

        final ImageView help=findViewById(R.id.help);
        help.setOnClickListener(this);
        //hide help image
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout=findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (Math.abs(verticalOffset)-appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange() == 0)
                {
                    //  Collapsed
                    help.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Expanded
                    help.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        //Hide keyboard on scroll
        NestedScrollView scrollView=findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    try {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Objects.requireNonNull(getCurrentFocus()).getWindowToken(), 0);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });



        //Banner ad
        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        //Interstitial
        InterstitialAd.load(this, String.valueOf(R.string.interstitial_ad_id), adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.toString());
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });




    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.help:
                //Popup help
                showInterstitial();
                AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder;
                final AlertDialog helpDialog;
                helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                View hView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.help_popup, null);
                helpBuilder.setView(hView);
                helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
                helpDialog.show();
                TextView helpHeading=hView.findViewById(R.id.help_heading);
                TextView helpText=hView.findViewById(R.id.help_textView);
                TextView helpClose=hView.findViewById(R.id.help_close);
                helpHeading.setText(getString(R.string.bonus));
                helpText.setText(getString(R.string.bonus_help));
                helpClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        helpDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                break;
            case   R.id.bonusArrowBack:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
            case R.id.button_check_eligibility_bonus:
                try {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Objects.requireNonNull(getCurrentFocus()).getWindowToken(), 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                showInterstitial();
                //1st option of doj
                if (beforeAprilRadio.isChecked()){
                    if (!basicOfSep.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                        basicForBonus= Integer.parseInt(basicOfSep.getText().toString().trim());
                        bonusCalDA= (int) (basicForBonus*0.06);
                        bonusCalEmoluments =basicForBonus+bonusCalDA;
                        //show popup with result

                        showBonusCalResult();

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter basic pay of Sep 2023", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    //2nd option
                }else if (betweenAprSepRadio.isChecked()){
                    if (!basicOfMar.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                        basicForBonus= Integer.parseInt(basicOfMar.getText().toString().trim());
                        bonusCalDA=(int) (basicForBonus*0.10);
                        bonusCalEmoluments=basicForBonus+bonusCalDA;
//show popup
                        showBonusCalResult();

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter basic pay of March 2024",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else {
                    bonusCalEmoluments=999999; //for showing negative result
                    showBonusCalResult();

                }



                break;
        }

    }

    private void showBonusCalResult() {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.myFullscreenAlertDialogStyle);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.result_bonus_cal_popup, null);
        builder.setView(view);
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        showInterstitial();


        //banner ads
        AdView resAdview=view.findViewById(R.id.res_adView);
        AdRequest adRequestRes = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        resAdview.loadAd(adRequestRes);


        //show Result
        TextView bonusPopupText =view.findViewById(R.id.result_bonus_text);

        if (bonusCalEmoluments<=42000){
            resultText="You are eligible to receive bonus Rs. "+bonusAmount;
            bonusPopupText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_res_green_background);
        }else{
            resultText="You are not eligible to receive bonus.";
            bonusPopupText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_res_red_background);
        }
        bonusPopupText.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}",resultText));


        //close
        ImageView close = view.findViewById(R.id.close_popup_res_all);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });



    }
        void showInterstitial(){
            if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                mInterstitialAd.show(BonusEligibilityActivity.this);
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
            }
    }
    }



Hi, did you get a solution to this? I'm facing a similar problem.

No, Not yet.....
